# How does one solve this second order non-linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y \, y'' + \frac12 (y')^2 - y' = 0$$

I can't figure out which approach I should use to solve this ... anyone got a hint?

Comment: because every term of the sum contains a derivative,  $y=constant$ is a solution

Comment: try to find an integrating factor

Comment: Hint: rewrite equation using $p=y'$

Comment: @Doc No thanks. (What are you *talking* about?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote $p=y'$ (my favourite substitution). We have
$$
y''=\frac{dp}{dx}=\frac{dp}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=p\frac{dp}{dy}.
$$
Rewrite equation:
$$
yp\frac{dp}{dy} + \frac12p^2 - p = 0.
$$
If $p=y'=0$, we have a solution $y=\mathrm{const}$. Let $p\not\equiv 0$:
$$
y\frac{dp}{dy} + \frac12p - 1 = 0.
$$
Separate variables:
$$
\frac{dp}{p-2} + \frac{dy}{2y}=0,
$$
and get
$$
\ln{|p-2|} + \frac12\ln{|y|}=C,
$$
or
$$
y'=2 + Cy^{-1/2}.
$$
Could you proceed from here?

Comment: yes, rest should be just seperation of variables?

Comment: @Christian, yep